# Unable to retrieve GET field in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to use **GET** in php, when i look at request url it's include there but when using `$_GET['data']` to fetch from request it shows that field doesn't exist or not define.

> Note:  In localhost problem doesn't encounter, only in live hosting
>   does.

**Localhost, Xampp with Apache and MySql, Windows 7, PHP-5.6**

**Live Host:
PHP-5.6**

In DevTools (Chrome):

```
Request URL: https://XXXXXXXXXXXX/admin/sorter.php?action=sort&data=%7B%22query%22%3A%22KVKfHQWE60uw4aFL2dYSp4nAWXk78irL7MmY4Bp7WMvBPg_PLUS_CdsZftwVxC7E2gjlSABpcr0hKYxOR3Ua6jgKCHIJbBlru35ZYCGwXSx6ky_PLUS_j0n4xB3BzDQYrxnhkEVl8_SLASH_7MmY4Bp7WMteLWJpMFo2q54pQXhWVwElglsGWu7fllj6qcS3HGrAJtSD1j_SLASH_rL4tbfDoJEgL1fEqKiuSyD72Gaq1WpzBRaMAzm_PLUS_FgRu1cs6Cm0zTdOI1vVeOByw0tU6R0ZHFdDLUHJei1jkRxe_SLASH_4EvOkySZIDEDI0btRsLmQBWguSS0cl5OkttdtJ7s9A8GR8qKCbs_PLUS_EhJjGTH9VixaDp4cmlij4YKeVgTjsI9zmwYeiq7BVTGK6a9ULdgbEvEI2Aduqce1kuQGx1ClL2AsOVPpLu48c1oFoWisqYI7qmM1V74kRVBXIfyw_EQUALS__EQUALS_%22%2C%22num%22%3A%221%22%2C%22table%22%3A%22work_order%22%2C%22sortby%22%3A%22ASC%22%2C%22field%22%3A%22w.wo_no%22%7D&archive_list=false
```

Request Method: GET

Query String:

```
action: sort
data:{
 "query":"KVKfHQWE60uw4aFL2dYSp4nAWXk78irL7MmY4Bp7WMvBPg_PLUS_CdsZftwVxC7E2gjlSABpcr0hKYxOR3Ua6jgKCHIJbBlru35ZYCGwXSx6ky_PLUS_j0n4xB3BzDQYrxnhkEVl8_SLASH_7MmY4Bp7WMteLWJpMFo2q54pQXhWVwElglsGWu7fllj6qcS3HGrAJtSD1j_SLASH_rL4tbfDoJEgL1fEqKiuSyD72Gaq1WpzBRaMAzm_PLUS_FgRu1cs6Cm0zTdOI1vVeOByw0tU6R0ZHFdDLUHJei1jkRxe_SLASH_4EvOkySZIDEDI0btRsLmQBWguSS0cl5OkttdtJ7s9A8GR8qKCbs_PLUS_EhJjGTH9VixaDp4cmlij4YKeVgTjsI9zmwYeiq7BVTGK6a9ULdgbEvEI2Aduqce1kuQGx1ClL2AsOVPpLu48c1oFoWisqYI7qmM1V74kRVBXIfyw_EQUALS__EQUALS_",
 "num":"1",
 "table":"work_order",
 "sortby":"ASC",
 "field":"w.wo_no"
}
archive_list: false
```

PHP code:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [action] => sort
    [archive_list] => false
)
```

I expect that it will show like
Output:

```
Array
(
    [action] => sort
    [data] => {query etc.}
    [archive_list] => false
)
```

Answer (score 0):

as a Workaround on my problem, i implement code that will check if the "**data**" field is not present then get the "**data**" using **parse_url**.

> `if (!(isset($_GET['data']))){
>       $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
>       $n_data=(parse_url($url));
>       parse_str($n_data['query'],$output);
>       $data= json_decode($output['data'],true);
>       }`

If any, can you advise if there's some filtering that remove the **GET['data']** variable upon **PHP** process. i already check my codes there's no redirect or any, that modify  **GET['data']**.